# Download statistics for packages published on pub.dartlang.org?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I created a package and published it a few months ago and saw it's *Popularity* increased, so I was wondering is there any way to see download statistics for my package ?

For example, PHP has https://packagist.org and every package has statistics like so:

[image: Packagist statistics]

Any idea for dart-pub?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is currently not available.

You can upvote this issue https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2714 to raise priority.

Comment: I see it's put on future milestone. Does that mean that this feature will be available in near future ?

Comment: Above issue is closed, to follow the discussion head over to https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2714

Answer (score 1):

Please upvote https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2714 to get first-class support for download counts.

In the meantime, you can view a package's popularity score, which is a *relative* download count vs. other packages.

Docs: https://pub.dev/help/scoring

> Popularity measures the number of apps that depend on a package over the past 60 days. We show this as a percentile from 100% (among the top 1% most used packages) to 0% (the least used package). We are investigating if we can provide absolute usage counts in a future version See [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2714) issue.
>
> Although this score is based on actual download counts, it compensates for automated tools such as continuous builds that fetch the package on each change request.

Example: https://pub.dev/packages/const_date_time/score

[image]